# How to Send Image Array by index From OneViewController to AnotherViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, json

i am newbie in iOS Development. i make an application that contain JSON data And i parsed that Data into Array and this Array Also Contain Another array it is Also parsed by index like as

```
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.storeViewTable reloadData];
    }
    self.storeViewTable.hidden=FALSE;
    }
    for(NSDictionary *dict in self.imageArray )
    {
    [self.imagesa addObject:@{@"demopage":[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]}];
    }
    NSLog(@"Array Count %@",self.imagesa);
    NSLog(@"Another array Count %d",[self.imageArray count]);
}
```

it is Give me Array As i want and now i Show this self.imagesa array by index by index when my TableviewCell Button Was Pressed then i add a tag TableViewCell button and Write is method Like as

```
preview.tag=indexPath.row;
```

i set a tag my Preview Button and is Action method like as

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);
if (row == 0)
{
    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[1][@"demopage"];
    [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
}
if (row == 1)
{
    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[2][@"demopage"];
    [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
}
}
```

Here showPreviewSeondSection is my Preview Button Pressed Actionmethod Here i have Only two Cell then it is Working Very Well and Send my self.imagesa array to PreviewViewController view Controller but in Future in my Application my TableViewCell was increase then how i Set For loop or if loop to Send Data to my PreviewView Controller please Give me Solution for that. 
when i edit my Code as myButton pressed event

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);

for (row = 1; row<[self.imagesa count]; row++)
{
    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[row][@"demopage"];
    [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
}
}
```

then it Display only First index data For all button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have noticed in your code is that... 
when row = 0 you are sending array at index 1
when row = 1 you are sending array at index 2
 so this can be done dynamically like so,

you don't need to pass the hard coded index, you need to pass row+1 index

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);

PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[row+1][@"demopage"];
[self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: but it is working when my index are increase in future?

Answer (score 0):

You need not write if condition, at the time of cell button action we will get the index.

You can send same data by using below code, If you want to send next object then you can increase row by 1.

```
NSInteger row = (button.tag+1);
```

If 'row' number is more than the number of objects in 'self.imagesa' array then  the application will crash throwing 'NSArray Outofbounds...' exception.

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);

// remove the commented part only

// if (row == 0)
// {
    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[row][@"demopage"];
    [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
//}
//if (row == 1)
//{
//    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
 //   preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[2][@"demopage"];
 //   [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
 //   NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
//}
}
```